# compare object to empty tuple with the 'is' operator in Python 2.x

Tags: python

I'm used to seeing `if obj is None:` in Python, and I've recently come across  `if obj is ():`. Since tuples are not mutable, it sounds like a reasonable internal optimization in the Python interpreter to have the empty tuple be a singleton, therefore allowing the use of `is` rather than requiring `==`. But is this guaranteed somewhere? Since which version of the interpreter?

[edit] the question matters because if () is not a singleton and there is a way of producing an empty tuple with a different address, then using `is {}` is a bug. If it is only guaranteed since Python 2.x with x > 0, then it is important to know the value of x if you need to ensure backward compatibility of your code. It is also important to know if this can break your code when using pypy / jython / ironpython...

Comment: It's definitely non-idiomatic.  Is there a justifiable use case for this?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: no special use case. I've found code using this, and it got me wondering if I should change it back, or update my opinion of the "is" operator. It would make sense to implement () as a singleton at the interpreter level...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Python 2 [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms) and Python 3 [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms):

> ... two occurrences of the empty tuple may or may not yield the same object.

In other words, you can't count on `() is ()` to evaluate as true.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the [id()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) method to get the internal id of the () :

```
>>> id(())
140180995895376
>>> empty_tuple = ()
>>> id(empty_tuple)
140180995895376        # same as the id of ()
>>> from copy import copy
>>> id(copy(empty_tuple))
140180995895376        # still the same as the id of ()
```

It looks like the () is effectively stored as a singleton in python (at least in python>2.6).

There is the same behaviour for the `""` empty string variable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what about `[]`?

Comment: this example proves nothing: it does not show that 2 empty tuples created in 2 different modules will be the same object in the end. Literal strings are interned in Python (it is the case since early in the 2.x branch), and while the empty string might well be a singleton too, there is no proof that what you see is not a side effect of interning.

Comment: @Toomai: lists are mutable, so you cannot have the empty list be a singleton.

Comment: @gurneyalex : that's why I tried to use the copy.copy() method to force to recreate a new empty tuple object, but I agree, I don't demonstrate the answer, I gave a method to verify the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-guaranteed implementation detail of current versions of CPython, so you won't necessarily be able to rely on it in other Python implementations, including Jython, IronPython, PyPy, and potentially future versions of CPython.

Using `is` appears to be about 0.04 μs faster on my system when comparing against a big list:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "x = range(10000)" "x is ()"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0401 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "x = range(10000)" "x == ()"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0844 usec per loop
```

Of course it could be considerably worse if you are comparing against something with a custom `__eq__()` method:

```
$ python -m timeit -s $'import time\nclass X(object):\n    def __eq__(self, other): return time.sleep(1)\nx = X()' "x == ()"
10 loops, best of 3: 1e+03 msec per loop
```

Still, if this efficiency difference is critical, I think that would point to a design problem.

Answer (score -1):

It's not about optimization. It's about objects comparisons. Python "is" is used to test object identity, then compare empty tuple "()" is not required to use "==" operator. In fact, anything in python can be compared with "is".

```
>>> obj = ()
>>> obj is ()
True
>>> isinstance(obj, tuple)
True
>>> obj is tuple
False
>>> type(obj) is tuple
True
>>> type(())
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(tuple)
<type 'type'>
>>> tuple == type(()) # value comparison with ==
True
```

Same for any other value:

```
>>> 333 is int
False
>>> type(333) is int
True
>>> isinstance(333, int)
True
```

Comment: But compare with executing the `a = 257` and `b = 257` statements. `a is b` can return `False`.

Comment: Yes. But this is related to python internals because id(a) can be different of id(b). type(a) is type(b) allways returns True. I tried to show that "is" operator is more suited to type comparisons, although instance objects can be compared too.

Comment: Excellent point: identity should work when comparing types. But in that case, `isinstance()` is usually the right thing to use instead.